# Want React higher-order component to re-render error messages after language has changed

Tags: reactjs, internationalization

I wrote a higher-order component (HOC) as per https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/higher-order-components.html.  It wraps a pure component that renders some sort of .

My HOC gets a validator function as a property.  When the value of the input changes, it calls validator(newValue).  validator() returns an error message or a blank string.  validator() methods may in turn call a method that translates its error message into a different languages depending on a user setting.

My problem is that if the user changes the language after an error message has been displayed, React does not re-render the error message in the newly selected language, because that only gets rendered when the validator() returns a different value, and the validator() is only called if the value the input it is wrapping changes.  The HOC has no way to know that the language has changed unless I make the language a property of the HOC.

I originally wrote the HOC to accept the chosen language as a property, then translate whatever error message its validator() property returned, but I thought this had a "smell" due to mixing of concerns.  I believe that the HOC should not have to be aware of the current language since that's not its concern.  Generating error messages in the chosen language should be the responsibility of each validator() method.  Does that make sense?

One hack I thought about is to have the changeLanguage() handler trick React into thinking that all the inputs have changes by iterating over all the inputs in the child DOM, unsetting, then resetting them to their current values.  That would force all the validator() methods to run again, this time producing error messages in the newly selected language.  It's a hack, of course.  I'd be switching one anti-pattern with another.

I know that changing the language is an edge-case.  I was going to set the language based on the Accept-Language HTTP header, but I read that this is discouraged, since Accept-Language can't always be relied upon to reflect what the user actually wants.  You can use that as a first guess, but have to give him a way of changing it if there is more than one choice.  So this opens the pandora's box.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

I can answer my own question.

The HOC renders error messages.  I can break that part out into it's own React component, and give it the language property so it will re-render whenever the language changes.  Easy!